# Codec Json doesn't send data to elasticsearch

Tags: json, elasticsearch

INPUT: json

```
{"userid": 125,"type": "SELL"}
{"userid": 127,"type": "SELL"}
```

LOGSTASH CONF FILE:

```
input {
kafka {
bootstrap_servers => ""
topics => ["topic1"]
codec => "json"
}
}
output {
amazon_es {
hosts => [""]
region => ""
aws_access_key_id => ''
aws_secret_access_key => ''
index => "indexname"
}

stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

stdout output:

```
{
"userid" => 127,
"@version" => "1",
"@timestamp" => 2018-10-18T13:54:37.641Z,
"type" => "SELL"
}
```

The output looks exactly like what I want. But this will just not go into the elasticsearch topic.
If I do not use the json filter the entire json goes as 'message' into ES.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured the problem. I was using a field called type in my json file  data which was causing the problem. logstash stored it as _type in ES which is no more allowed with the newer versions of elasticsearch. And that is why if my type was 'BUY' it would take the entry and if it was 'SELL' it would reject it. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use json filter?

```
input {
    kafka {
        bootstrap_servers => ""
        topics => ["topic1"]
    }
}

filter {
    json {
        source => "message"
    }
}
output {
    amazon_es {
        hosts => [""]
        region => ""
        aws_access_key_id => ''
        aws_secret_access_key => ''
        index => "indexname",
        custom_headers => {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    }

    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but I have the same issue. The stdout works perfectly and I get the output as shown above but the data does not go into the elasticsearch index. If I remove the json filter/ json codec then the data goes as a message field into ES.

Comment: It should be about the output plugin then. I noticed that all of the curl examples on the Amazon docs add  "content-type" header, so,  I added a line to the example config via "custom_headers" config option. See: https://github.com/awslabs/logstash-output-amazon_es/blob/1ddbd00e98ab1c79e5fd9ac57fac756eb8c2b328/lib/logstash/outputs/amazon_es.rb#L248.

Comment: Hi, the code I wrote is actually working for the input given above which is a simple example. I tried it again. The data goes into ES. But with the following input it sends the first data (line) to ES but then does not send anymore data in it when I add a new line. INPUT ----> {"userid": 102,"type": "BUY","orderid": 1208,"price": 200,"qty": 80,"pairid": 3,"pairname": "ABC-EFG","timestamp": "2018-05-22T07:50:00Z"}

Comment: if I have a file with multiple lines like these only a few are randomly put into the ES index not all of them.